# Adding an href to a "submit" in HTML

Tags: html

I have this submit method

```
<tr><td><input  type = "submit" value='Register'</td></tr>
```

and trying to attach

```
<a href="something.html">Click on meeee</a>
```

Any sugestions ?
So far i came up with just letting it be as a link , but thats not what it needs to be .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<input type='submit' />` element is generally used to submit the content of a `<form>` element, so you would need to create a `<form>` with an `action` attribute that pointed at your target location :

```
<form action='your-target'>
    <!-- Contents -->
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Basically, if you want to just direct the user, use a link (`<a> tag`). Otherwise, if you need to actually post some contents to the server, you should use a `<form>` that posts accordingly (and then you could redirect server-side after your processing was finished).

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute of the `<form>` determines the URL it will be submitted to.